# Error handling in AWS Lambda

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am building an Android application whose back end is in python which runs as an AWS Lambda function. The invocation type is RequestResponse. Sometimes the app fails to invoke the Lambda function. What I can't figure out is how to get the specific error returned by the function in the response and log it. All I get is the type of error which is "Unhandled". Please help.

Comment: Failed to invoke or error on lambda code? You can check the cloud logs.

Comment: Cloudwatch is not saving any logs for some reason.

Comment: You are calling the Lambda function via the AWS SDK for Android? You aren't using API Gateway?

Comment: Yes with lambda InvokerFactory method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [Monitoring tab in the AWS Lambda function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions.html) does not show any executions, then it sounds like the invocation is failing or being denied.

You could look at the [AWS CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html) logs to see how the request was received and handled.

If nothing is showing in CloudTrail, then your request never made it to AWS or was rejected before processing (eg out-of-date credentials?).

Comment: but it does work most times. I was looking for a way to get the specific error and show it in the android app.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an escaping exception. Just make sure you catch it then present the details in your response payload.

We use [this little tool](https://github.com/bespoken/bstpy) to test our Python lambdas. It will help you figure out the exception. If you use it with the rest of the [BST Tools](https://github.com/bespoken/bst) you can expose the lambda even on the internet while running it locally in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add permissions for CloudWatch in Lambda and now it is logging.